# Changing custom taxonomy's slug as required?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a section in a plugin i am making where admin can add custom taxonomies and custom post types as required. the admin will create a custom taxonomy by selecting a name(that will be used as slug), then create a custom post type and select the above created taxonomy as it's parent.

those are been added to a private DB table.

On init `action('init',)`... i have a class that runs through this database and register the custom post type/ taxonomies create previously and `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` to connect things up.

now my issue is. when the admin go back to the same screen and edit a taxonomy name(which also changes the slug) i update the DB according to the new changes. although my class see the changes and register them,when i refresh the page it doesn't  seem to actually change.

My question is:
is there anything i need to do to update that taxonomy ?

Sorry for the long text thanks.

Comment: The test is actually not long enough ;) please show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Lol yea i know sorry for that - well the general question would have been if i change the slug of a taxonomy reregister the taxonomy and use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` , would i need to use anything else to update it ?

Comment: You may need to re-save your Permalinks which flushes the cache for the re-write rules.

Comment: fixed the issue, it appears that what i were looking for was to change the taxonomy slug. what i did is, ones admin change the name of a taxonomy, update wp-taxonomy table, and search for my old taxonomy value, and updated it to the new one

Comment: @NetaMeta You can always answers your own question in detail in hopes it helps others that may run into the same issue.